# How to "Remote Desktop" to Mac from Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

Is there a way I can "Remote Desktop" from my Windows 10 to my Mac in the same network?

or anything similar?

thanks

Comment: What’s wrong with TeamViewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [VNC](https://www.google.com/search?q=vnc&oq=vnc&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (There are a lot of VNC programs)
- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.us/)
- [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en)

Here is a good [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/180953/3-free-ways-to-remotely-connect-to-your-macs-desktop/) about these three options.